# C++ Template Inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I couldn't find any similar questions with my Googling' skills, so hopefully SO can help. (Sample header psuedocode below)

```
namespace randomNamespace{
template <typename A, typename B>
class Shape{
    public:
        Shape(int);
        ~Shape();

        bool insert(std::pair<A,B> ab);
    private:
        std::vector<std::pair<A,B> > someListOfPairs;
};
}

class Square : public Shape<string, string>     //causes error requiring template before '<'
{
public:
    Square(int);    //When defined it is Square(int x) : Shape(x); as an initialization list to call superclass constructor
    ~Square();

    bool insert(std::pair<string, string> p);
private:
    //Shape<string, string> someShape    -- see question #3
};
```

1) What is the proper syntax for inheriting a template'd generic base class?

2) Does Class Square have access to someListOfPairs (not talking about it being private), such as when I call Square's insert(pair of strings), it will then call Shape's insert(pair of generic type)? (Also how would this actually be implemented??)

3) Would I have to define an object of Shape someShape to properly use the Shape class members even though it is already using inheritance?

Comment: Watch out: `Square::insert` *hides* `Shape<string,string>::insert`.

Comment: How would I be able to call Shape<A,B>::insert from Square's insert without having a dedicated object declared of type shape? (Question #2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) What is the proper syntax for inheriting a template'd generic base
>   class?

There's nothing wrong with the syntax of inheritance, you just need to specify the namespace of your base class:

```
class Square : public randomNamespace::Shape<std::string, std::string> { ...
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> 2) Does Class Square have access to someListOfPairs (not talking about
>   it being private), such as when I call Square's insert(pair of
>   strings), it will then call Shape's insert(pair of generic type)?
>   (Also how would this actually be implemented??)

You could call the `insert` member function of `Shape` from the member function of `Square` in the following way:

```
bool Square::insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string> p) {   
  randomNamespace::Shape<std::string, std::string>::insert(p);
  // ... 
  return true; 
}
```

> 3) Would I have to define an object of Shape someShape to properly use
>   the Shape class members even though it is already using inheritance?

Yes you would have to initialize the base class in the initializer list of `Square`s constructor:

```
Square::Square(int a) : randomNamespace::Shape<std::string, std::string>(a) {}
```